# Get values of a property from array of objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an list of objects:

```
[class RetailerItemVariant {
    sku: 008884303996
    isAvailable: true
    price: 70.0
}, class RetailerItemVariant {
    sku: 008884304030
    isAvailable: true
    price: 40.0
},
...
```

What's the best way to extract an array of the SKU's in Java 8? e.g.:

```
["008884303996", "008884304030", ...]
```

Im new to Java and this is very easy in Javascript using the map() function but I haven't been able to find a similarly simple way of doing it in Java...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you use Java 8, the `stream api` can help you here:

```
List<String> skus = itemList.stream()
          .map(Item::getSku)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with stream java 8:

```
List<String> listSku = list.stream().map(r->r.getSku())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 3):

Also in Java 8 there are `map` you can use :

```
List<String> listSku = listRetailerItemVariant.stream()
                       .map(RetailerItemVariant::getSku)
                       .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

It varies from your *start collection* and your *end structure*, but your basic code should look like this:

```
mylist
     .stream()
     .map(variant -> variant.getSku())
     .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)))
```

As start structure, if you use Arrays instead of collections move from `myList.stream` to `Stream.of(variantArray).map()`.

And as for your end structure, adjust if instead of an `ArrayList::new` you want a HashSet (`HashSet::new`) or a linked list (`LinkedList::new`)

and if you have many, many item variants and you'd like to collect their Skus fast and in any order, consider *parallel stream processing* by adding `parallel()` to the `stream()` function:

```
mylist
     .stream()
     .parallel() // for parallel processing
     .map(variant -> variant.getSku())
```